# How does tension affect torque in a pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Let's say there's a pulley with a massless cord wrapped around it and tied to a mass below on the right. I know that torque is equal to α*Fsinθ. However, if I draw an FBD of the mass, T - mg = -ma. Shouldn't F in the above equation be equal to -ma? Why is it equal to T instead?

[image: here is an example of what I'm referring to]

Comment: Torque about what?

Comment: @BobD torque about the center of the pulley

Comment: FWIW, "Drum" might be a better word than "pulley" in the illustration above. "Pulley" usually implies a contrivance that changes the direction of a line without changing the magnitude of tension in the line. The wheel in that kind of pulley does not feel any torque. (At least, not in the ideal case.) Contrivances that experience torque in proportion to the tension in a line that is wrapped around a cylinder often are called "drum," or "capstan," or "winch."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing a FBD of the pulley, not the mass. If you do a FBD of the pulley it shows that the only external force acting on the pulley causing rotation is the tension in the cord, $T$. Therefore $F$ in your equation has to be $T$.

Hope this helps.